# Count word frequencies of each word in a list in dataframe

Tags: python, string-matching, word-frequency

I have created a list of words associated with a certain category. 
For example:

```
care = ["safe", "peace", "empathy"]
```

And I have a dataframe containing speeches, that on average consist of 450 words. I have counted the number of matches for each category using this line of code:

```
df['Care'] = df['Speech'].apply(lambda x: len([val for val in x.split() if val in care]))
```

Which gives me the total amount of matches for each category.

However i need to review the frequencies of each word in the list. I tried using this code to solve my problem.

```
df.Tal.str.extractall('({})'.format('|'.join(auktoritet)))\
                           .iloc[:, 0].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
```

I've tried different methods but the problems is that i always get partial matches included. For example hammer would be counted for ham.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build on Akash answer, and managed to get the frequencies of prespecified words stored in a list and then counting them in the dataframe, by simply adding a line.

```
from collections import Counter

word_count=Counter()
for line in df['Speech']:
   for word in line.split(' '):
       if word in care:
           word_count[word]+=1

word_count.most_common()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Counter which is available from collections package

```
from collections import Counter
word_count=Counter()
for line in df['speech']:
   for word in line.split(' '):
      word_count[word]+=1
```

it will store count of all words in word_count.
Then You can use

```
word_count.most_common()
```

to see the words with highest frequency.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The problem is the words i need frequencies for are rarely the most common ones. That's why i want to count the words based on the list.

Comment: you can use reverse function on word_count.most_common()  for seeing the words which occur very less

Comment: The code will be list(reversed(word_count.most_common()))

Answer (score 0):

You could transform each word in a tuple with 1 as second element `('word', 1)` and sum it for each word in list.

The output will be a list of tuples with the words and the frequencies:

```
[('word1', 3), ('word2', 10) ... ]
```

This is the main idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But would this solve the issue with partial matches? If im looking for "ham", hammer would be considerd a match because it has "ham" in it.

Comment: If your use equality of strings, you won't have problems. You don't need to use `regex` for this situation. If you type `"ham" == "hammer"` you'll get `False` since the strings are different.